# SQLigt: extract only specific month

Tags: sqlite

I am struggling to select specific month with SQLite.

```
SELECT * 
FROM order
WHERE strftime('%m', transaction_date) = '10';
```

I have tried this and it shows "[21:55:30] Query finished in 0.000 second(s)." but nothing showed up in Grid View. This is what I have in **order** table. I have tried changing the date to 10-23-2015 format as well but it didn't work. I don't want to use **LIKE** because these is an assumption that I can't see the date format. 
[image]

Comment: Can you show us an example of data in the `transaction_date` column?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have edited the original post.

Comment: Your transaction_date column might not be a datetime type. try string splitting and getting the second.

Comment: @TahaPaksu There is no datetime type in SQLite.  Dates are stored as text.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen, I forgot. Long time no use.

Answer (score 1):

Dates are stored as text in SQLite, so you can just use substring here:

```
SELECT * 
FROM order
WHERE SUBSTR(transaction_date, 1, 2) = '10';
```